# temporary suspension of ember observers

Tags: ember.js

With Ember.js, I have the following scenario:

My Class has a property that require some manipulation at instanciation.
To achieve that, I'm calling a function that does the work from init. I also want to **observe** this propery change, so that if consumer will set new value at run time I will run my manipulation logic over the new value.
The problem is, that as part of the init flow, I'm setting myself the new value to the property after manipulation, and this invokes the trigger (as expected). I do not want this code to run twice.

Consider the following code. 'here' will be printed twice to the console.

```
    var MyObj = Ember.Object.extend({

        prop: null,

        init: function init() {

            this._super.apply(this, arguments);
            this._applyProp();

        },

        _applyProp: function prop() {

            console.log('here');

            var prop = this.get('prop');

            if (prop === 'Dan') {

                prop = 'Hi' + prop;
            }

            this.set('prop', prop);

        }.observes('prop')

    });

    MyObj.create({prop: 'Dan'});
```

Any advice will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Having an observer that sets the property it is observing seems like a bad idea. Your particular example could be achieved using a computed property getter/setter:

```
var MyObj = Ember.Object.extend({
  prop: function(key, value) {
    if (value !== undefined) {
      if (value == 'Dan') {
        return 'Hi ' + value;
      }
      return value;
    }
  }.property(),
});
MyObj.create({prop: 'Dan'});
```

Would this be sufficient to cover your use cases?

Comment: This looks like a good direction but the snippet itself will not do the work. The reason is that the computed-setter will not be called if a value is set in instantiation time. To achieve this we must:

 `MyObj.create().setProperties({prop: 'Dan'});`